# How to unbind a shortcut in a terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Ubuntu 18.04

I'm using the embedded terminal in VSCode and there is a keyboard binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> which is pretty useful and convenient and I would not like to rebind it. However the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> shortcut works as <kbd>Backspace</kbd> when the IDE-embedded terminal is focused which is really annoying. Moreover <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> for backward character delete seems useless for me.

I tried to open a terminal and then opened to *Edit* -> *Preferences*, then *Shortcuts* but I did not found the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> in there. So how to simply disable it? Is there some config file?

Comment: what is your IDE?

Comment: @MarkJ.Adams VSCode. I use it for C-programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> is not a shortcut in the usual sense. Many terminal emulators conventionally send `^?` (aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>) for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> (see [this U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226333/70524) for details). This is *not* usually configurable behaviour, short of modifying the source code.

`^?` is the control code for ASCII Del and `^H` (aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) for ASCII Backspace (see [this informative post](http://web.archive.org/web/20120621035133/http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html) for a lot more on that).

So, if you don't want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> to delete a character, you may need to change:

- the control code your terminal sends for the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. GNOME Terminal usually defaults to `^?` (ASCII DEL), IIRC, so you need to set it to `^H`. In GNOME Terminal, that's in *Edit* -> *Profile Preferences* -> *Compatibility*:

  [image]

  **If your terminal doesn't have an option to configure this and sends `^?` for <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, then the next two steps *will* break <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.**
- the control code that the pseudo-TTY uses for `erase`

  Check what it is now:

  ```
  $ stty -a | grep erase
  intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
  swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
  ```

  If it's `erase= ^?`, you'll need to change that:

  ```
  stty erase '^H'
  ```
- the control code that your shell uses for erasing the previous character. In bash, that defaults to *both* `^H` and `^?` if `^?` is the `erase` character for the controlling TTY.

  Check what it is now:

  ```
  $ bind -p | grep backward-del
  "\C-h": backward-delete-char
  "\C-?": backward-delete-char
  ```

  Remove the `\C-?` binding, and add a `\C-h` binding if needed:

  ```
  bind -r '\C-?'
  bind '\C-h: backward-delete-char'
  ```

  Add these to your `.bashrc` to save these settings.

---

Or you can change your IDE shortcut.

Comment: Indeed changing the stty `erase` breaks the backspace key. If I want to do the change on a remote shell (no way to configure the terminal graphically), is there another way than breaking the backspace key? Isn't there a config file for this?

Comment: Even if it's a remote shell, the first part has to be done by whichever terminal emulator you're using (say, PuTTY for an SSH client), because ultimately that's where the Backspace-escape code translation first happens.

Comment: By "first part" you mean changing the control code that the terminal send to the backspace key, right? I there a way to do it on the command line? (my terminal does not have a graphical interface as in your answer

Comment: @Giuseppe some terminal emulators may have a (text) config file you could edit. What's the actual issue and environment you have?

Comment: I am running Archlinux, with LXQt as Desktop manager, and QTerminal. I found a qterminal.ini file, but I did not find anythig for 'backspace' or 'Ctrl+H' in it. My issue is that in an SSH to a Ubuntu machine, the Control-H combination is bound to backspace, which is inconvenient when using emacs.

Comment: It might not be directly configurable, but try switching the "Emulation" https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3ORE.png. Setting it to "Linux" or "macbook" makes it send `^?` for Backspace when I tried it out.

Comment: I found only one field `Emulation=default` in the `qterminal.ini`, and changing the value to `linux` or `macbook` or other available values did not change the behavior.

Comment: Did you try using QTerminal's preferences GUI?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well (that's where I found the other available values, like `solaris`).

Comment: Then perhaps you should post a new question on [unix.se]. Also include what you get when you type Ctrl-V Backspace with each of the emulations.

Comment: Oh, I just tried Ctrl-V backspace with the `linux` emulation and the output is `^?`. But Ctrl-H still acts as backspace... But am I correct to assume that now I can change the control code for the `erase` of the pseudo-TTY without breaking backspace?

Comment: @Giuseppe I think so. As noted in the answer, the default bash setting is to have both `^H` and `^?` delete the last character.

Comment: Yes, it works! Actually the step to do next was `bind -r '\C-h'` (which was set to `backward-delete-char`), and now Ctrl-H does not act as backspace anymore. Thanks a lot @muru!! So to summarize what I did: I changed the emulation of my terminal emulator from `default` to `linux`, then verified that "Ctrl-V backspace" outputs `^?`, and then `bind -r '\C-h'`.